# Iterate data in HTML page through Jsoup android

Tags: java, android, jsoup, html-parsing

I am working on a functionality where I get `HTML` page, from where I have to extract desired data(product image, product name, product price etc) and display it in `Recylerview`

For parsing HTML page I use Jsoup library: https://jsoup.org/

**URL**    https://www.snapdeal.com/search?keyword=watch&sort=plrty

I am new this concept of `HTML` page, don't know how to extract my required data in an array.

My android code:

```
private void observeLiveData () {

    snapdealViewModel.searchProduct("watch", "plrty").observe(this, new Observer<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {

            try {

                String html = responseBodyResponse.body().toString();
                Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
                Elements elemensts = document.select("product-tuple-image");

                for (Element element : elemensts) {

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    });
}
```

I am stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `html` in your question above provides the same content as I got when I invoked `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.snapdeal.com/search?keyword=watch&sort=plrty").get();` then this ...

```
String html = responseBodyResponse.body().toString();

Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements elements = doc.select("div.product-tuple-description");
for (Element element : elements) {
    String link = element.select("a.dp-widget-link").first().attr("href");
    String title = element.select("p.product-title").first().attr("title");
    String price = element.select("span.product-price").first().text();

    System.out.println(String.format("Link=%s, Title=%s, Price=%s", link, title, price));
}
```

... will print:

```
Link=https://www.snapdeal.com/product/iik-collection-black-analog-watch/680673440602, Title=IIK Collection Black Analog Watch, Price=Rs. 227
Link=https://www.snapdeal.com/product/rosra-multicolor-analog-watches-pack/638328550475, Title=Rosra Multicolor Analog Watches - Pack of 2, Price=Rs. 273
Link=https://www.snapdeal.com/product/curren-brown-analog-watch/674386848559, Title=Curren Brown Analog Watch, Price=Rs. 179
Link=https://www.snapdeal.com/product/abrexo-abx1157silver-analog-watch-for/684706734736, Title=Abrexo Abx-1157-Silver Analog Watch - For Men, Price=Rs. 499
... etc
```

Notes:

- The use of `.first()` is brittle, you'll probably want to test the return value from these select calls before finding the correct element.
- The select method uses a CSS selector syntax (more details [in the docs](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)) but briefly; "a.dp-widget-link" means "find all elements of type 'a' having the class 'dp-widget-link'".

Comment: Jsoup.connect() will directly get html page ? . How do I implement in Retrofit (Android library) way?

Comment: I am getting elements  size as 0

Comment: Yes, `JSoup.connect()` will connect **and** parse. It basically wraps the `parse` method which you are currently invoking. However, it's possible that you would prefer to read the HTML on a different thread to the one on which you parse and display the results so you might prefer to continue with your current approach i.e. read it and then delegate the parsing to your `RecyclerView`. This is, I think, secondary to your question since your question (and the above answer) addresses **how** to read the data you want from the HTML response.

Comment: Re this: "I am getting elements size as 0", this suggests that the HTML you are parsing is **not** the same as the HTML retrieved by making the `connect()` call. I'd suggest inspecting/comparing the HTML which you pass to your `RecyclerView` against the HTML returned by the `connect()` call.

Comment: @karthikkolanji Re this: "I am getting elements size as 0" , this may suggests also that the HTML viewed in a browser may be generated by some Javascript or from an AJAX call...

Comment: Mistakenly I was usig GsonConverter , I changed it to https://github.com/slashrootv200/retrofit2-html-converter, and it worked.